# Storing selected language option in cookie/localSession

Tags: reactjs, cookies, internationalization, next.js, session-cookies

I would like my Next.js app to remember which language the user prefers, therefore I want to store it in a cookie on client side.
I have 2 language options: EN & FR.

By default the language is set up for English (no cookie, `myapp.com/`), but once the user clicks on EN preference, the URL changes to `myapp.com/en` and this selected language should be stored. The same applies for French.

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useState(false);

        <Link
            href={`/${router.locale === 'en' ? 'fr' : 'en'}`}
            locale={false}
        >
            <a
                onClick={() => {
                    setLanguage((language) => !language);
                    // setCookie({});
                }}
            >
                {` ${language ? 'en' : 'fr'}`}
            </a>
```

Where and how can I use the cookie or session storage so the backend can see it?

Comment: Might be worth having a read through [Leveraging the NEXT_LOCALE cookie](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#leveraging-the-next_locale-cookie).

Comment: `const setCookie = (locale) => { document.cookie = NEXT_LOCALE=${locale}; window.location.reload();}` This was my set up with calling the setCookie in my onClick function, but no luck with that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @Camilo I tried what I mentioned in my previous comment. Using Next_Locale stored in hook, which I called in my onClick function, which would work, but I don’t really know what to call inside the function -onClick setCookie()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can leverage the [`NEXT_LOCALE` cookie](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#leveraging-the-next_locale-cookie) to persist the user's language preference. This will override the accept-language header that is usually used by Next.js built-in i18n.

This function sets a cookie with an expiry date of one year from now, at the root path of the domain.

```js
const setCookie = (locale) => {
    document.cookie = `NEXT_LOCALE=${locale}; max-age=31536000; path=/`
}
```

---

**Recommendation:** Unrelated to the issue you raised, I would also recommend you use a button rather than an anchor to handle the language switching, as it's doing more than just simple navigation at this point.

```js
<button
    onClick={() => {
        const locale = router.locale === 'en' ? 'fr' : 'en'
        setCookie(locale)
        router.push(router.asPath, undefined, { locale })
    }}
>
    {router.locale === 'en' ? 'fr' : 'en'}
</button>
```

Comment: your recommendation is bad (or poorly coded at least), as if it's a language selector inside another route, with your suggestion the route would completely change and go to the root page instead of the page where the user is

Comment: @SoldeplataSaketos The example is a direct conversion of OP's code to use `router.push`. It wasn't meant as a generic language switch that could be used anywhere. That being said I might as well update it to fit that purpose.

Comment: @juliomalves I'm using next 13.5. Storing NEXT_LOCALE cookie doesn't effect preferred language. I can see in dev tools (localhost) that my cookie value is "fr" but on every new tab or private window, app defaults to English "en". Any tip?

Comment: @WolfWar It's possible `NEXT_LOCALE` no longer works with the `app` router from Next.js 13. If support for it got dropped, you may have to implement your own solution to persist the preferred language. For instance, you could check the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie value in a middleware, and setup a redirect yourself to the right locale.